# monerod v0.12.2.0 does not start on Linux because of "./monerod: error while loading shared libraries: libpcsclite.so.1"

Tags: monerod, linux

monerod v0.12.2.0 does not start on Linux because of "./monerod: error while loading shared libraries: libpcsclite.so.1". How do I resolve this particular issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular issue is resolved in CLI & GUI v0.13.

<s>First, this error is caused by the `libpcsclite` dependency (which is required by Ledger) not being properly compiled statically. Fortunately, however, this error is trivially resolved by installing `libpcsclite1`. That is:</s>

`sudo apt-get install libpcsclite1`

**Fedora:**

`dnf install pcsc-lite`

If, after installing this dependency, `monerod` still does not run and throws the same error, I'd recommend installing `libpcsclite-dev` (Ubuntu / Debian) or `pcsc-lite-devel` (Fedora)

**Sources:**

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8ok4hg/v01220_binaries_released/e0e0zoq/
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8ok4hg/v01220_binaries_released/e04w05u/